# Do hot gases that don't have an infrared absorption spectrum, emit infrared light, regardless of the specifics of their molecular composition?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, gas

My layperson's understanding is that, although solids and liquids usually radiate across a wide variety of wavelengths modeled by the blackbody spectrum, gases do not because the geometry of their molecules can only be affected by absorbing/emitting certain discrete wavelengths, a la quantum mechanics.

However, from NASA's publication, "[Basics of Radio Astronomy](https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/radioastronomy/)", Chapter 3, "*[The Mechanisms of Electromagnetic Emissions](https://radiojove.gsfc.nasa.gov/education/educationalcd/RadioAstronomyTutorial/Workbook%20PDF%20Files/Chapter3.pdf)*" we have the following:

> **Thermal Radiation**
>
> Did you know that any object that contains any heat energy at all emits radiation? [...]
>
> All the matter in the known universe behaves this way.
>
> Some astronomical objects emit mostly infrared radiation, others mostly visible light, others mostly ultraviolet radiation. The single most important property of objects that determines the radiation they emit is *temperature*.
>
> Electromagnetic radiation is produced whenever electric charges accelerate—that is, when they change either the speed or direction of their movement. In a hot object, the molecules are continuously vibrating (if a solid) or bumping into each other (if a liquid or gas), sending each other off in different directions and at different speeds. Each of these collisions produces electromagnetic radiation at frequencies all across the electromagnetic spectrum. However, the amount of radiation emitted at each frequency (or frequency band) depends on the temperature of the material producing the radiation.
>
> [...]
>
> Any matter that is heated above absolute zero generates electromagnetic energy. The intensity of the emission and the distribution of frequencies on the electromagnetic spectrum depend upon the temperature of the emitting matter.

This would seem to indicate that **regardless of the specifics** of the gas molecule -- whether it's a noble gas or a diatomic molecule or a triatomic molecule etc. -- just the very nature of the molecules moving, bumping into each other, changing direction and speed, which is all a function of temperature, means that they will emit a variety of radiation *"at frequencies all across the electromagnetic spectrum"*.

This contradicts some answers I've read on this site, though, for example that Argon can't lose heat radiatively:

> You also ask about Argon, but that is a completely different situation. Atomic argon gas has a rich infrared spectrum, that has been studied in the lab for some time (e.g. Humphreys & Kotkowski 1952), but the upper levels of these transitions aren't going to be excited by collisions at 200 K. I expect therefore that **an Argon gas just couldn't cool radiatively** [emphasis mine]. [source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/522745/how-does-a-moderately-hot-gas-emit-radiation)

And:

> Absorption is negligible in the visible and in the IR for argon and for homonuclear diatomics like H2, N2, and O2. So according to Kirchhoff's radiation law, emissivity is negligible too. **These gases do not cool by radiating** [emphasis mine]. [source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/522745/how-does-a-moderately-hot-gas-emit-radiation)

These answers seem to contradict NASA's publication. Which one is correct? I would tend to weigh what NASA published more strongly, strictly on appeal to authority grounds, but that doesn't mean it is right, of course.

Comment: Even gases that don't have a dipole moment are showing induced dipole radiation, but it is very weak in comparison to a black body. While gases are transparent below their electronic excitations, they do show Rayleigh scattering, which is the same phenomenon in an external electromagnetic field rather than the internal fields caused by collisions.

Comment: @FlatterMann are you familiar with any links showing experimental data? Would be curious to see how much in practice. It seems hard to measure cause the gas would need to be in a container and the container would be heated by the gas and emit radiation itself …

Comment: You are correct. Experimentally it is probably very hard to measure these emissions on the bench accurately (if at all?). I am not aware of such measurements. All the emission spectra that I have ever heard about involve rotational, vibrational, electronic and nuclear spin states, all of which are most likely many orders of magnitude stronger. I am not a spectroscopist, though, so I just don't know enough about what has and has not been measured.